# Search and extract date with user supplied patterns

Tags: python, regex, django, datetime, date-format

I'm writing a django application to collect and analyse log files from various different applications. I want the user to be able to supply either a date format, or a regex that will match the date format, so that I can track the start and end time of the file.

I'd rather not have the user supply both a regex and a date format, but I'm thinking there isn't a way around it.

I want to extract the first and last datetime within the file, and parse it into a datetime object within python. As I said though, the format of the date will be user-supplied in some way.

Is there a way to build out a regex from a date format or vice versa? Or am I just going to require a format and a pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your users can supply a dateformat in [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) format, there is no need to use regular expressions as well. `strptime` is flexible enough to handle most date formats.

**EDIT**

Since `strptime` does not allow for searches in arbitrary text, you will probably need a regular expression. It is not trivial to turn a strptime pattern into a regular expression, but Fredrik Lundh did it for you. You can find the code here: http://effbot.org/librarybook/time.htm

Look for the phrase: "Example: A strptime implementation"

Comment: Hans, but I need to be able to find the pattern in arbitrary text.. the first part is extracting from a file, the second part is parsing.

Comment: So basically your problem is that you want do a search on the date pattern, but strptime will only work on fixed strings?

Comment: It is possible to transform a date pattern into a regular expression. How much work this will be depends largely on the freedom you allow your users to input their dates.

Comment: That could be what I'm looking for, thank you. Since the date formats of log files should be fairly well formed, I'm going to try dateutil.parser first, but will fall back to the strptime regex builder from the link you posted. Thank you again.